# Chrome scrollbars not appearing, just white gap?

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where on my page scrollbars aren't appearing in Chrome on a Mac (haven't tried on a PC). It does work okay in Firefox however.

I've tried the following...

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  all: unset;
  display: block;
}
```

To no avail

[image: No Scrollbar]
[image]

Comment: What happens if you scroll by mousewheel or trackpad gesture?

Comment: It works fine I just can t see it @LarsBeck

Comment: Alright, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the expected behaviour to me, idle scrollbars are invisible on macOS, you can try the following to make them always visible.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```